# Populate listview with different item set on a specific user action

Tags: android, android-listview

I have listview which shows a set of certain items. This listview is visible in a dialog (not dialog fragment). There is an action item in this dialog which says use current location. When user clicks on this, geo-coordinates are fetched and sent to my server to fetch fresh data. When the data is fetched, I first insert it into db and then use the cursor to populate the view.

How can I repopulate same list view with different data set?

Comment: Fresh data? previous data will be void? and post necessary code!

Comment: Post your code here!!!